# Javascript How use window.open to open a link in a specific page/tab?

Tags: javascript, window.open

I've a php form page. This page can as well reload forms already filled in the past by entering the formid number.

```
http://localhost/form.php?idform=19
```

In that page, I've added a javascript window.open which shows the 50 last forms created. In that new window, I'd like to put a link for each formid. If I click on one of those links, I'd like to get back to the main page (form.php) and get the page loaded with the specific formid.

Does window.open is able to manage this? If so, how?
here is the sample of the window.open used in the form.php

```
<a href="http://localhost/formlist.php" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://localhost/formlist.php','1400166928639','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=400,top=200');return false;">FL</a>
```

Please advise.
poy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new "window" (tab) can be given a name using the second parameter to `window.open`, which you have set to `'1400166928639'`.

If you can `window.open` subsequently with that same parameter value, the tab will be re-used (assuming it's still open), and the new URL will be loaded into it.

Edit:

If you want to open a URL in the original window from another opened window, you can use the other window's window.opener property to reference back to the original window:

```
window.opener.location.href = 'http://localhost/formlist.php';
```

Comment: Sounds great but this has to be done on the main window, not the new one. Is it a way to set that number while loading the page at beggining?

Comment: thanks! but I think I messed up now lol. So, main page is form.php which has a link to open a new webpage called formlist.php which contains links with id's that will be reopen on click, in form.php. What you suggested doesn't work but I guess it's due to my sillyness isn't it?

Comment: It should still be possible; on the formlist.php page, have the links open as: `<a href="http://localhost/form.php?idform=19" onclick="window.opener.location.href = 'http://localhost/form.php?idform=19'; return false">form 19</a>`